# Selecting a field in macro and cutting it out in a loop

Tags: vba, excel

I need to select a field of cells (table) in an Excel worksheet, cut the selection out and then paste it into a new separate sheet. There are like thousand tables below one another in this worksheet and I want to automaticly cut them out and paste them into separate sheets. The tables are separated by cells with the # symbol inside but I dont know if it is helpful in any way. When I recorded this macro for the first table it run like this:

```
Sub Makro1()
Range("A2:AB20").Select
Selection.Cut
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Now I want to make a loop which would go through the whole worksheet, dynamically select every table which would be delimited by the # sign in a col A and paste it into new sheet. I dont want to choose exact range A2:AB20, but I want to make selection according to this # sign.

Here's a screenshot
[image]

Comment: can you provide a screenshot how the tables are separated? just post a link in a comment, somebody will include it in the post...

Comment: I don't understand how autofilter can help....I need to cut(or copy) the rows 9:15, 28:32 etc. and paste each of them into new single sheet.

Comment: sorry, oversaw the "new sheet" part. my bad!

Comment: do you want to copy only the data (9:15) - or all the rows between the '#', i.e. 3:19?

Comment: 3:19 would be better...

Comment: Btw. I don't insist on using the hashmark as a reference point...I would welcome any suitable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. You might need to adjust the top 4 constants to your need:

```
Sub CopyToSheets()
    Const cStrSourceSheet As String = "tabulky"
    Const cStrStartAddress As String = "A2"
    Const cStrSheetNamePrefix As String = "Result"
    Const cStrDivider As String = "#"

    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim lngMaxRow As Long, lngLastDividerRow As Long, lngRowCount As Long
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim lngCounter As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'Delete old worksheets
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each wsTarget In Sheets
        If InStr(wsTarget.Name, cStrSheetNamePrefix) Then wsTarget.Delete
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    With Sheets(cStrSourceSheet)
        Set rngSource = .Range(cStrStartAddress)
        lngLastDividerRow = rngSource.Row
        lngMaxRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Set rngSource = rngSource.Offset(1)
    While rngSource.Row < lngMaxRow
        If rngSource = cStrDivider Then
            lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
            Set wsTarget = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
            wsTarget.Name = cStrSheetNamePrefix & " " & lngCounter
            lngRowCount = rngSource.Row - lngLastDividerRow - 1
            rngSource.Offset(-lngRowCount - 1).Resize(lngRowCount).EntireRow.Copy _
                wsTarget.Range("A1").Resize(lngRowCount).EntireRow

            lngLastDividerRow = rngSource.Row
        End If
        Set rngSource = rngSource.Offset(1)
    Wend

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This will populate an array with the indicies of all your hash values. This should provide you with the reference point that you need to collect the appropriate data.

```
Sub FindHashmarksInColumnA()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim indices() As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim iMax As Double
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    i = 0
    iMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("A:A"), "#")
    ReDim indices(1 To iMax)

    For Each c In ws.UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells
        If c.Value = "#" Then
            i = i + 1
            indices(i) = c.Row
        End If
    Next c

    ' For each index,
    ' Count rows in table,
    ' Copy data offset from reference of hashmark,
    ' Paste onto new sheet in appropriate location etc.

End Sub
```